# Why does openapi-generator create InlineObjects?

Tags: c#, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

to create a client for my API. It's mostly working ok, but the generator creates a lot of `InlineObject` types that encapsulate parameters that include types of any complexity, e.g `Dictionary`, `IFormFile`, `Stream`

For example,

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<FileUploadResponseAPIModel>> MyApiClientMethod(InlineObject11 inlineObject11 = default(InlineObject11))
    {
    }
```

Where InlineObject11 is defined as

```
public partial class InlineObject11 : IEquatable<InlineObject11>, IValidatableObject
{
    
    [JsonConstructorAttribute]
    protected InlineObject11() { }
    
    public InlineObject11(Stream rebalanceTradeFile = default(Stream))
    {
        // to ensure "rebalanceTradeFile" is required (not null)
        this.RebalanceTradeFile = rebalanceTradeFile ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("rebalanceTradeFile is a required property for InlineObject11 and cannot be null");
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "RebalanceTradeFile", IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public System.IO.Stream RebalanceTradeFile { get; set; }
```

What is the point of this? Why isn't the client generated to take `Stream rebalanceTradeFile` instead of wrapping it into an `InlineObject`? How can I fix it? This is breaking a bunch of my tools that use older versions of the generated client.

Comment: my excitement when this was the first result on google, only to realise it was my question to begin with and there's still no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline Object is created from inline schema, e.g. https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/inline_model_resolver.yaml#L15-L24 is a schema with 2 properties defined inline for the payload with the MIME type `application/json`.

To avoid OpenAPI Generator automatically generating a model for the inline schema, one can define the model separately ([example](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml#L686-L724)) and use `$ref` instead:

```
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
```

Comment: What if I don't want to create a whole separate model *at all* just for an endpoint that takes Union[Thing1, Thing2]? The SDK function should just accept thing 1 or thing 2 instead of having to create a whole other model that is just a union.

Answer (score 2):

Using `title` field in schema object, the model name is `title` name instead of `InlineObject`.